# Android. Эффективное использование Bitmap.

Tags: android

При прокрутке изображений в галерее, сначала отображается изображение в плохом качестве, затем оно в течении 1 сек принимает хорошее качество. Как такое реализуется?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это делается примерно так: Берется изображение, декодируется с высоким сэмплингом, рисуется. Потом в фоне декодируется в более высоком качестве и заменяется изображение.
Все это скорее всего делается в кастомном BitmapDrawable.

Есть хорошая библиотека для изображений. Можете просто ее использовать https://github.com/square/picasso

Answer (score 1):

Галерея устаревший класс, воспользуйтесь viewpager

Comment: Наверное ТС имеет в виду не класс, а стандартное приложение "Галерея".